# Java method hidden but not static

Tags: java, oop

I am trying to understand how the below prints `HelloWorldExtendedHelloWorld,false`. I would expect it to print "true" since the `whichMethod` is overridden in the `ExtendedHelloWorld` class. If both methods were public and static, then I think it would make more sense since then both the parent and the child method would exist and I would be calling the parent method because I am using the `HelloWorld` reference. In this case, however, the methods are not static - so I was expecting then to be overridden. Anyway, the parent method is private, how can it be called from the outside? Can someone please help? Thanks!

```
public class HelloWorld {
    public HelloWorld() {
        System.out.print("HelloWorld");
    }

    public HelloWorld(int age) {
        System.out.print("HelloWorldAge");
    }

    private boolean whichMethod() {
        return false;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        HelloWorld example = new ExtendedHelloWorld(5);
        System.out.println("," + example.whichMethod());
    }
}

class ExtendedHelloWorld extends HelloWorld {
    public ExtendedHelloWorld(int age) {
        System.out.print("ExtendedHelloWorld");
    }

    public boolean whichMethod() {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: You're not extending the method and in fact can't extend it, since it's private. Also note that it is permissible to use white space in your code. I've edited your code for readability.

Comment: How can it be called externally then? `example.whichMethod()`

Comment: It's not being called "externally". The main method is within the class, and so the private method is visible to main. If the main method was elsewhere, your code would not compile, since example is a HelloWorld variable, and the private whichMethod within it would not be visible.

Comment: Ok, thanks. It makes sense now. Somehow unfortunately I cannot mark your answer as an answer.

Comment: I've made my comments an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not extending the whichMethod method and in fact can't extend it, since it's private. Also, it's not being called "externally". The main method is within the class, and so the private method is visible to main. If the main method was elsewhere, your code would not compile, since example is a HelloWorld variable, and the private whichMethod within it would not be visible.